# Translation of "mental block" in German

Tags: english-to-german

I've searched for the german translation of this phrase *mental block* and noticed that there are several translation such as *mentaler Block*, *Blockade*, *Lösungsblockade* etc.

Which one of them best fits my translation needs?

> **en:** According to affective filter hypothesis the learner cannot utilize the input since there is a mental block.
>
> **de:** Gemäß der Affektive-Filter-Hypothese kann ein Schüler den Input nicht nutzen, da es eine Blockade gibt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Blockade" as in your translation is probably not enough to translate *mental block* ("Blockade" could be anything - from active rejection by the learner to noisy environment, whatever). "Mentale Blockade" is most probably the right translation and a standing expression.

"Lösungsblockade" is more about solving conflicts. I don't see any here. But it might be in the context.

Comment: Is "Gemäß" a perfect prepositon for hypothesis or could I also use "nach" and" laut?

Comment: *Gemäß*, *laut*, *nach*, *entsprechend* and *zufolge* are perfectly suitable when referring to a hypothesis. Note all of them are used a bit differently and ask for the dative

Answer (score 3):

In addition to trofo's answer:

*Mental block* can also be translated as *Denkblockade* ([1](https://books.google.de/books?id=zbKFlU-6fjMC&lpg=PA693&dq=denkblockade%20mental%20block&hl=de&pg=PA693#v=onepage&q=denkblockade%20mental%20block&f=false), [2](https://books.google.de/books?id=TZTNNVd2srkC&lpg=PA101&dq=denkblockade%20mental%20block&hl=de&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=denkblockade%20mental%20block&f=false)) or *Denkhemmung* ([3](https://books.google.de/books?id=Nr-7KpabEtsC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=mental%20block%20denkhemmung&source=bl&ots=0dC35ylu0u&sig=xZWrbPz_HHQFsyenFe0VBU4ekgE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2z-vA-c_NAhXFVRQKHU4aDxkQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=mental%20block%20denkhemmung&f=false), [4](https://books.google.de/books?id=OEBN1Uo-efwC&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=mental%20block%20denkhemmung&source=bl&ots=RoW0oUobO6&sig=1Xn7KerQX3PSTE6KIReH1u2odvw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2z-vA-c_NAhXFVRQKHU4aDxkQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=mental%20block%20denkhemmung&f=false)), but I think *Denkblockade* is much more common than *Denkhemmung*.

Comment: _Mentalsperre_ - das hat so einen modernen Klang. :)